# I have two simultaneous Schengen visas. How does the 90/180 rule work?

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, portugal, schengen-visas

I am an Indian passport holder, living in the US (with work visa, no green card).

I had a Schengen visa issued by the Netherlands valid from 12th January, 2017 to 11th January, 2019 and spent 69 days between 28th August, 2017 to 10th November, 2017 in Schengen.

I had to visit Portugal in December and I applied and was given another Schengen visa issued by Portugal, valid from 10th December, 2017 to 10th December, 2018. So, they are overlapping.

I realize I am not allowed to have two overlapping Schengen visas in the same passport, but since I do have it, can I stay more than 21 days using the Portugal visa from December to February 2018?

Comment: I wonder... Why did you ask for another visa? Are they the same type? I'm actually surprised they issued another visa, especially one that ends before the first one, if they're the same type.

Answer (score 5):

No. The 90/180 rule applies to *any combination* of C visa, and also to the use of D visa outside the issuing country.

The normal case would be successive C visa, but concurrent visa are no different.